# Set PercentageRelativeLayout margin programmatically

Tags: android

Please, how do I set the percentage margin for the imageview programmatically.

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/rating_thumb"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/thumb" />

</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 7):

After several hours of googling and tweaks, I finally got the answer.

```
imageView =  (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.rating_thumb);
PercentRelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (PercentRelativeLayout.LayoutParams) imageView.getLayoutParams();
PercentLayoutHelper.PercentLayoutInfo percentLayoutInfo = layoutParams.getPercentLayoutInfo();
percentLayoutInfo.leftMarginPercent = 15 * 0.01f; //15 is the percentage value you want to set it to
imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Comment: setLayoutParams called requestLayout()

Comment: cannot resolve PercentRelativeLayout.LayoutParams  , This class was deprecated in API level 26.1.0.
consider using ConstraintLayout and associated layouts instead